# Oracle query to get min or max value of a datatype

Tags: sql, oracle

Does Oracle have a function or query that will return the min or max value of a datatype? From the documentation I know that the minimum  value of a date field is January 1, 4712 BCE. Is there anyway to get that date value from a select statement?

```
Select ?something? from dual;
```

Comment: THe docs - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020

Comment: No to my knowledge, you have to appeal to the documentation

Comment: OldProgrammer - A link to the docs and nothing else, wish I could down vote a comment :(

Comment: Jaime, thanks for the answer, that's what I thought; I was hoping someone might know of a function that I could not find using Google or Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you write a little piece of code, then then answer is *yes*. Not exactly a single `SELECT` (unless you put all that into a function), though.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    datum date := trunc(sysdate);
  3  begin
  4    while 1 <> 2 loop
  5      datum := datum - 1;
  6    end loop;
  7  exception
  8    when others then
  9      dbms_output.put_line('Last valid date = ' ||
 10        to_char(datum, 'dd.mm.yyyy bc'));
 11  end;
 12  /
Last valid date = 01.01.4712 BC

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

That was quick (I mean, code takes no time to execute). For other datatypes it isn't that fast (such as *which is the smallest valid integer?*), at least not by using the same principle.

Comment: I figured something like this was the only option, thanks for response.

Answer (score 1):

Use first value in *julian* calendar

```
select to_date(1, 'j') from dual
```

displayed results depends on server and client settings, but it is a date `4712-01-01 BC`.

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=672b55a4b1f26e844608a79100a96452)</sup>**